# Google Cloud Endpoints with Tomcat (instead of Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

Will I be able to employ Google Cloud Endpoints on a Tomcat Server (that runs as container inside Google Container Engine) by adding suitable libraries to a dynamic web project, or is this technology strictly tied to Google App Engine and can only be deployed there?

I don't require anything special in terms of authentication against Google accounts, and would just like to use the technology's annotations to implement my REST/JSON protocol in a simple (and elegant) way.

I guess the answer is no (i.e. technology is strictly tied to Google App Engine), but want to be sure before looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Cloud Endpoints currently relies on the App Engine stack for its internals.

Comment: Looks as if the situation is about to [change](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/manage-your-APIs-with-Google-Cloud-Endpoints.html) a bit: "Based on the Open API Specification (formerly known as Swagger), Cloud Endpoints supports backends running on Google App Engine Standard or Flexible Environment, Google Compute Engine or Google Container Engine."